# Django socket communication

Tags: django, sockets, websocket, licensing, django-channels

I have a Django server with a list of devices and their corresponding MAC addresses. I have also created firmware for these devices, and I want to license them using my Django webserver in order to prevent the firmware from being copied onto other chips. The problem I'm facing is that the data will be sent to my web backend every 10 minutes (which could be reduced to 1 minute in the future). Additionally, I want the communication between the devices and the web server to be two-way, so that I can disable the devices at any time by sending a message.

I'm unsure of how to handle this situation. Would Django channels be a useful solution in this case, and if so, how can I implement them? The firmware is written in C++.